TicketGrantingTicketImpl Exception - Central Authentication Service 7.0.2
I use the delegation identity provider from github. It runs ok, and authorized my account in cas successfully.
2024-03-26 15:05:02,752 ERROR 
[org.apereo.cas.util.serialization.AbstractJacksonBackedStringSerializer] - <Cannot read/parse [{"@class":"org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl","@id":1,"id":"TGT-1-********qFm6SjQ17y...] to deserialize into type [class org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl]. This may be caused in the absence of a configuration/support module that knows how to interpret the fragment, specially if the fragment describes a CAS registered service definition. Internal parsing error is [Cannot construct instance of `org.pac4j.oauth.credentials.OAuth20Credentials` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 2090] (through reference chain: org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl["authentication"]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthentication["credentials"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.ClientCredential["credentials"])]>
2024-03-26 15:05:02,758 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - <INVALID_TICKET
 DefaultTicketStringSerializationManager.java:deserializeTicket:60
 DefaultTicketStringSerializationManager.java:lambda$deserializeTicket$1:49
 Unchecked.java:lambda$supplier$38:1695
>
2024-03-26 15:05:52,249 INFO [org.apereo.cas.services.mgmt.AbstractServicesManager] - <Loaded [2] service(s) from [EmbeddedResourceBasedServiceRegistry].>
2024-03-26 15:06:35,242 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.util.serialization.AbstractJacksonBackedStringSerializer] - <Cannot read/parse [{"@class":"org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl","@id":1,"id":"TGT-1-********qFm6SjQ17y...] to deserialize into type [class org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl]. This may be caused in the absence of a configuration/support module that knows how to interpret the fragment, specially if the fragment describes a CAS registered service definition. Internal parsing error is [Cannot construct instance of `org.pac4j.oauth.credentials.OAuth20Credentials` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 2090] (through reference chain: org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl["authentication"]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthentication["credentials"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.ClientCredential["credentials"])]>
2024-03-26 15:06:35,342 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.util.serialization.AbstractJacksonBackedStringSerializer] - <Cannot read/parse [{"@class":"org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl","@id":1,"id":"TGT-1-********qFm6SjQ17y...] to deserialize into type [class org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl]. This may be caused in the absence of a configuration/support module that knows how to interpret the fragment, specially if the fragment describes a CAS registered service definition. Internal parsing error is [Cannot construct instance of `org.pac4j.oauth.credentials.OAuth20Credentials` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 2090] (through reference chain: org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl["authentication"]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthentication["credentials"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.ClientCredential["credentials"])]>
2024-03-26 15:06:35,353 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.util.serialization.AbstractJacksonBackedStringSerializer] - <Cannot read/parse [{"@class":"org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl","@id":1,"id":"TGT-1-********qFm6SjQ17y...] to deserialize into type [class org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl]. This may be caused in the absence of a configuration/support module that knows how to interpret the fragment, specially if the fragment describes a CAS registered service definition. Internal parsing error is [Cannot construct instance of `org.pac4j.oauth.credentials.OAuth20Credentials` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 2090] (through reference chain: org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl["authentication"]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthentication["credentials"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.ClientCredential["credentials"])]>
2024-03-26 15:06:52,256 INFO [org.apereo.cas.services.mgmt.AbstractServicesManager] - <Loaded [2] service(s) from [EmbeddedResourceBasedServiceRegistry].>

But the console logs the problem below (tickets registry into redis).
org.pac4j.oauth.credentials.OAuth20Credentials is a class file under org.pac4j.pac4j-oauth:6.0.0 pom. No parameterless constructor is provided by default.  The code works under cas version 6.6.0.
cas.authn.pac4j.github.id=xxx
cas.authn.pac4j.github.secret=xxx
cas.authn.pac4j.github.client-name=github
cas.authn.pac4j.github.callback-url=https://xxx.goho.co

How to fix it?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xJ7s34gZ6y47oN2zslLlOKdTqkZSiYjC/view?pli=1

I too faced this error in my CAS 7.0.4 version. Problem is with Jackson not able to deserialize TicketGrantingTicketImpl.class because it is not able to understand how to construct object for OAuth20Credential.class and OAuth2AccessToken.class.
As I am using CAS overlay project, what i did is I override both  OAuth20Credential.class and OAuth2AccessToken.class and made the below changes, which basically helped jackson library used inside CAS project understand how to deserialise these classes and construct their objects.
package org.pac4j.oauth.credentials;

import java.io.Serial;

import org.pac4j.core.credentials.Credentials;

import com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuth2AccessToken;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

/**
 * This class represents an OAuth credentials for OAuth 2.0 an authorization code.
 *
 * @author zhangzhenli
 * @since 1.9.0
 */
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class OAuth20Credentials extends Credentials {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1370874913317625788L;
    private String code;

    private OAuth2AccessToken accessToken;

    /**
     * For OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow.
     *
     * @param code       the authorization code
     */
    public OAuth20Credentials(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}

For OAuth2AccessToken.class I made below changes where I simply added @JsonCreator annotation in one of the constructors, keeping rest of the code as it is:
// No-argument constructor for Jackson
@JsonCreator
public OAuth2AccessToken(@JsonProperty("accessToken") String accessToken) {
    this(accessToken, null);
}

You can try the solution this way and see if it fixes it for you.
